# How do I create a page (with a url) that displays only views blocks

Tags: views, blocks, rules, 7

I have been using views to create all of my pages.  I am wondering if there is a way to set up a page (with url) that is initially blank.  I want to use context to place view blocks on this page based on user roles.  If a context is not matched, then the url should act as though the page does not exist (would I need a rule for this?)  How can I build this?

Comment: Why dont you attempt it and if you have a specific issue, share your findings and post a question?

Comment: BTW, what is the best way to share you findings on StackExchange, which is all QnA?

Comment: It is valid to answer your own question if that question + answer would be useful for others. When you are creating a question there is a checkbox for "Answer your own question".

Answer (score 1):

One way of solving your issue is by installing the following modules:

- [Empty Page](https://drupal.org/project/empty_page)

  > The Empty Page module is a simple empty page solution. It provides an interface that assists in managing "empty" menu callbacks, mostly used for pages that only consist of blocks.
- [Path Access](https://drupal.org/project/path_access)

  > The Path Access module gives site administrators an additional layer
  >   of access control to all pages of a Drupal site.
- [Chain Menu Access API](https://drupal.org/project/chain_menu_access) - required by Path Access module

  > Chain Menu Access API allows your module to chain its own menu access
  >   callback functions into other modules' menu router entries.

After installing all the above modules, try to implement the following steps:

- Add new empty page from `admin/structure/empty-page/add`.
- locate blocks you need to display on the created page using Context with **Path** condition and **Blocks** reaction.
- Now from Access Path settings `admin/config/people/pathaccess` specify who should access the created page and who should not per user role.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Page manager part of the [Ctools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) module to create pages like this, you might need to expand this further but it should give you a starting point

Comment: does ctools have a GUI or is that all done in programming?

Comment: CTools doesn't have a GUI as such, but Page manager does, it also goes very well hand-in-hand with Panels